# Can i concatenate 2 values and put them in a dropdown menu

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I am making this excel sheet and I want to keep it as simple as possible ant not use VB.
So I don't even know or think if its possible. I know how to use the concatenate function but can I concatenate 2 dropdown menus to make a third one?

ex

```
Dropdown box A : Blue ,Yellow, Green   Dropdown box B : Violin, Guitar, Piano
Dropdown box C : Blue ,Yellow, Green   Dropdown box D : Violin, Guitar, Piano


                         Dropdown E: Blue Violin
                                     Green Guitar
So the options from Dropdown menu E depends on the previous boxes.
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you using the List (from Data Validation) to make the drop downs?  If so, this is relatively simple.

Comment: @Tim Ya Im using the list from data validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this (though it is probably not the most elegant way) would be something like this:

```
1.  Create the color list
    a.  Enter the values for the color list in an area in your spreadsheet, one value per cell.  For purposes of this example, let's use A8:A10 (Blue, Yellow and Green).
2.  Create the instrument list
    b.  Like step 1A above - for this example, let's use A12:A14 (Violin, Guitar, Piano).
3.  Create four dropdowns that use the two lists created:
    a.  For purposes of this example, Drop Down A and C are in A3 and A5.  Data Validation is set to List, with the source being A8:A10.
    b.  For the instruments, Drop Down B and D are in C3 and C5, with their source being A12:A14.
4.  Create a third list that will concatenate the two values for each group:
    a.  A and B:  =Concatenate(A3, " ", A5)
    b.  C and D:  =Concatenate(C3, " ", C5)
    c.  Again for this example let's put these in A17:A18.
5.  Create the fifth dropdown (E) and set it's list source to A17:A18.
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Note that the formulas in 4a and 4b go in cells A17 and A18, respectively.

I have no doubt there are more elegant solutions out there, but this is one way to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much!! You have no idea how much you helped me :)